# Pattern in Python: diamond of stars

Tags: python

Loops question in Python:

```py
n=int(input())
k=n//2
y=k+1

for i in range(0,y):
    for j in range(0,y-i):
        print(" ",end='')
        
    for j in range(0,i):
        print("*",end='')
        
    for j in range(0,i-1):
        print("*",end='')
    print()
    
for i in range(0,k):
    for j in range(0,i):
        print(" ",end='')
        
    for j in range(0,k-i+1):
        print("*",end='')
        
    for j in range(0,k-i):
        print("*",end='')
    print()
```

How can I rectify my code? It shows extra space and a star is missing in the end.

Output for `input=5`:

```
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
```

[image]

Here this code is right in while loop: but not working here in for loop

```
n=int(input())
i=1
k=n//2
y=k+1
while(i<=y):
   
    j=1
    while(j<=y-i):
        print(" ",end='')
        j=j+1
    j=1
    while(j<=i):
        print("*",end='')
        j=j+1
    j=1
    while(j<=i-1):
        print("*",end='')
        j=j+1
        
    print()
    i+=1
i=1
while(i<=k):
    j=1
    while(j<=i):
        print(" ",end='')
        j=j+1
        
    j=1
    while(j<=k-i+1):
        print("*",end='')
        j=j+1
    j=1
    while(j<=k-i):
        print("*",end='')
        j=j+1
          
    print()
    i=i+1
```

What is the difference between two codes?

Answer (score 1):

Jay Patel already answered your question, but you might be interested by a simpler implementation of your code.

```
n=int(input())
even = n%2==0

for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
    print(('*'*i).center(n))

for i in range(n-2-even, 0, -2):
    print(('*'*i).center(n))
```

##### Output

```
  *  
 *** 
*****
 *** 
  *
```

Comment: can we use that code using k only instead of y there?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what "k" and "y" represents.

Answer (score 0):

In 2nd for loop you have used `k` instead of `y`

```
n=int(input())
k=n//2
y=k+1

for i in range(0,y):
    for l in range(0,y-i):
        print(" ",end='')
        
    for j in range(0,i):
        print("*",end='')
        
    for m in range(0,i-1):
        print("*",end='')
    print()
    
for i in range(0,y):
    for l in range(0,i):
        print(" ",end='')
        
    for j in range(0,k-i+1):
        print("*",end='')
        
    for m in range(0,k-i):
        print("*",end='')
    print()
```

output :

```
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
```

Comment: but why to use y?